# jQuery selector for a variable containing HTML

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have a div that contains HTML data (this changes and is user generated).

Included in this data are various anchor tags. I need to find all the tags, and remove the `href` attribute.

However, I don't seem to be able to get my selectors just right.

Here is the the jQuery:

```
var divForHtml = $('#Content');   
divForHtml =  $(divForHtml +'a').attr('href', '');
```

Once that has been done, I need to send this variable to a function that will then continue processing the HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this situation `divForHtml` is a jQuery object; so you can't simply append the *string* `' a'` to it to build a new selector.

Instead, try using the [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find) method, to search the descendants of the matched element;

```
divForHtml.find('a').attr('href', '');
```

Although you might like the [`removeAttr()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr) method more;

```
divForHtml.find('a').removeAttr('href');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var divForHtml = $('#Content');
$('a', divForHtml).attr('href', '');
```

or - even easier:

```
$('#Content a').attr('href', '');
```